# How to center a folium map on a marker when the map is wrapped in a div

Tags: python, css, flask, folium

I have a folium map that is loaded into a `<div>`-Element with JavaScript. The `<div>` is smaller tha the map and i hide the rest of the map with css `overflow: hidden`. My problem is that the position i am focusing on the map, is in the hidden area. Is there any way to make the map focus on the point in the middle of my `<div>`?

Some screenshots:
I made the background color gray for better visibility of the elements.

The map with the marker (not visible)
[image: Map with marker not visible]

The map without `overflow: hidden`. The map is bigger than the containing `<div>` and my screen.
[image]

What i am trying to achieve:
[image: wanted result]

Code:

Requires folium and flask

app.py

```
import folium
from flask import Flask
from folium import Marker

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return template


@app.route('/map')
def map():
    folium_map = folium.Map(location=[39.750855, -101.533079])
    Marker(location=[39.750855, -101.533079], popup='Marker').add_to(folium_map)
    return folium_map.get_root()._repr_html_()


template = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(128,128,128);">
    <div id="smallDiv" style="height: 40vh; width: 100%; background: aqua; overflow: hidden;"></div>
    <script>
        fetch('/map')
        .then(repsonse => repsonse.text())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById('smallDiv').innerHTML = data;
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height of the map to the same height as that of the div using `folium.Map(height=...)`